# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next_page' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a site for a client and this bit of code has always worked in the past, but suddenly is no longer working.  No one has touched the core code and I'm not even sure where to look for a resolution.

We use Docebo (an LMS) and in the test we require the student to select an answer before they can click "Next Question".  If they haven't selected the answer, the button is grayed out and unclickable.  I believe the framework is using the YUI library for this.

I don't get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next_page' of undefined " error until I select the answer.  Once the error happens, the button doesn't become functional.

Chrome's console points to this bit of code...

```
function controlTotQuestion()
{
var info = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('answer_info');
if(tot_question == 0)
{
setTimeout(function() {
  if(YAHOO.buttonObjects.next_page)
    YAHOO.buttonObjects.next_page.set('disabled', false);
  if(YAHOO.buttonObjects.show_result)
    YAHOO.buttonObjects.show_result.set('disabled', false);
  if(info)
    info.style.display = 'none';
}, 0);

}
else
{
setTimeout(function() {
  if(YAHOO.buttonObjects.next_page)
    YAHOO.buttonObjects.next_page.set('disabled', true);
  if(YAHOO.buttonObjects.show_result)
    YAHOO.buttonObjects.show_result.set('disabled', true);
  if(info)
    info.style.display = 'block';
}, 0);
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to read the property `next_page` of `YAHOO.buttonObjects`. Therefore `YAHOO.buttonObjects` is undefined. In other words, whatever `YAHOO` is, it no longer has an element called `buttonObjects`. Is `YAHOO` an external library? If so, check whether they've removed the `buttonObjects` functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This was exactly what I needed.  Looks like the core code was using it as an external library.  I was able to download the older version and place it internally and everything works now (awaiting our QA team to confirm of course)!

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should check whether the new version of the library has a replacement for `buttonObjects`. You may at some point end up in a situation where you need a feature/bug-fix that's only available in newer versions of `YAHOO`.